# Client-side Code signing technical explanation

Tags: hash, code-signing, signing, pki, pkcs#11

Question: Is there a technical explanation how client side code-signing can be used in enterprise enviroments with open source tools like signtool or openssl?

In my usecase, I want to create a hash of a code file and sent the hash on a seperate server. This server is just used for signing. On this server are also the certificates and private keys stored.
After the hash is signed, I want to transfer the signed hash back to the client and envelope the signed hash with the code file e.g. a .exe file.

In the "Mircosoft Code Signing Best Practices", it's also recommended to first create a hash of the data and then sign the hash value with a private key.

Unfortunately I can't find any further informations how to implement this with seperate steps, described as abow.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/7/af7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b/best_practices.doc

"In practice, using public-key algorithms to directly sign files is inefficient. Instead, typical code-signing procedures first create a cryptographic hash of the data in a file—also known as a digest—and then sign the hash value with a private key. The signed hash value is then used in the digital signature. The digital signature can be packaged with the data or transmitted separately. A separately transmitted digital signature is known as a detached signature."